# integration of definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int\limits_{-1}^{\frac 3 2}|x\sin(\pi x)| dx $$

Can you help me find the domains in which the function will be positive and in which it be negative? I mean how to determine in which range it will positive or negative?

Comment: Hint: Can you compute the zeros of this function?

Comment: another hint: calculate sign of $x$ and $\sin (\pi x)$ separately at first.

Comment: Yes thanks I got positive for -1 to 1 and negative for 1 to 3/2.

Answer (score 0):

Without the absolute value bars, the integrand is an even function. Then for nonnegative $x$, $\sin \pi x$ is nonnegative on intervals $[2n,2n+1]$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, so the same is true of $x\sin\pi x$.

By evenness, then, you can extend the result to the intervals $[-(2n+1),-2n]$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ as well.